# MAUI and iOS: icon set or app icon set named "appicon" error

Tags: c#, ios, maui

I have a `NET8` `MAUI` application and I like to test it on an iOS simulator. When I try to run the application, I get this error

> None of the input catalogs contained a matching stickers icon set or app icon set named  "appicon".

After binging a bit, I found this post on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/14721) where they say:

> In the info.plist you have
>
> XSAppIconAssets
> Assets.xcassets/appicon.appiconset The AppIcon file
> name is icon.svg
>
> What worked for me was making sure those name matched, ex rename the
> svg to appicon.svg or in info.plist to icon.appiconset

or

> I had the same problem what fixed it for me was renaming my icon file
> from "orpheus_icon.png" to "orpheus.png" and changing this line in the
> info.plist to Assets.xcassets/orpheus.appiconset

Those answers were related to the NET7 and the previous version of MAUI. I think something has changed since then.

In my project, I have the folder **Platform > iOS > AppIcon.appiconset** and the autogenerated images. In **Resources**, I have the *appicon.svg*.

[image]

In the *Info.plist*, I have

```
<key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
<string>Assets.xcassets/appicon.appiconset</string>
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: What is the BuildAction of the svg file?

Comment: Have you checked if there is MauiIcon Section  in your project file? You may refer to the [Add an app icon to a .NET MAUI app project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/app-icons?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=android#change-the-icon).